# Parameter 0 of constructor in com.****.Controller requires a bean of type 'com.*****. service'. Spring boot application wont run

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, mysql-workbench

My code:

```
package com.qa.project.domain;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
@Entity

public class RunStat {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column
    @NotBlank
    private double runTime;
    
    @Column
    @NotBlank
    private double runDistance;
    
    @Column
    @NotBlank
    private int runCalories;

    public RunStat() {
    }
    
    public RunStat(Long id, int runCalories, double runDistance, double runTime) {
        this.id = id;
        this.runCalories = runCalories;
        this.runDistance = runDistance;
        this.runTime = runTime;
        
    }
    public RunStat(int runCalories, double runDistance, double runTime) {
        this.runCalories = runCalories;
        this.runDistance = runDistance;
        this.runTime = runTime;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public double getRunTime() {
        return runTime;
    }
    public void setRunTime(double runTime) {
        this.runTime = runTime;
    }
    public double getRunDistance() {
        return runDistance;
    }
    public void setRunDistance(double runDistance) {
        this.runDistance = runDistance;
    }
    public int getRunCalories() {
        return runCalories;
    }
    public void setRunCalories(int runCalories) {
        this.runCalories = runCalories;
    }
}
```

```
package com.qa.project.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.qa.project.domain.RunStat;
import com.qa.project.repository.RunStatRepo;

@Service
public class RunStatService {

    private RunStatRepo repo;

    public RunStatService(RunStatRepo repo) {
    this.repo = repo;
    }
    
    public RunStat addStats(RunStat stats) {
        return this.repo.save(stats); 
         
    }
    public List<RunStat> getAllStats(){
        return this.repo.findAll();
    }
    
    public RunStat updateStats(Long id, RunStat newStats) {
        Optional<RunStat> optionalRunStat = this.repo.findById(id);
        if (optionalRunStat.isPresent()) {
            RunStat existingRunStat = optionalRunStat.get();
            existingRunStat.setRunTime(newStats.getRunTime());
            existingRunStat.setRunDistance(newStats.getRunDistance());
            existingRunStat.setRunCalories(newStats.getRunCalories());
            return this.repo.save(existingRunStat);
        }
        return null;
        
    }
    public boolean removeStats(Long id) {
        this.repo.deleteById(id);
        return !this.repo.existsById(id);
    }
    public RunStat readById(Long id){
        Optional<RunStat> optionalRunStat = this.repo.findById(id);
        //if (optionalRunStat.isPresent()) { //get rid of this line but use for other methods later
        return optionalRunStat.get();
    }
}
```

```
package com.qa.project.repository;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.qa.project.domain.RunStat;
import com.qa.project.service.RunStatService;

@Component
@Repository
public interface RunStatRepo extends JpaRepository<RunStat, Long>{
    public RunStat addStats(RunStat stats);
    public List<RunStat> getAllStats();
    public RunStat updateStats(Long id, RunStat newStats);
    public boolean removeStats(Long id);
    public Optional<RunStat> findById(Long id);
}
```

```
package com.qa.project.rest;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnBean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.qa.project.domain.RunStat;
import com.qa.project.service.RunStatService;


@RestController
public class RunStatController {
    
    private RunStatService service; 
    
    
    public RunStatController(RunStatService service) {
        super();
        this.service = service;
    }

    @PostMapping("/createStats")
    public RunStat addStats(@RequestBody RunStat stats) {       
        return this.service.addStats(stats);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/getStats")
    public List<RunStat> getAllStats(){
        return this.service.getAllStats();
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/removeStats/{id}") 
    public boolean removeStats(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return this.service.removeStats(id);    
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/getAUser/{id}")
    public RunStat readById(@PathVariable Long id){
        return this.service.readById(id);
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/editUser/{id}") //changes whole record, so you have to input whole new record to replace
    public RunStat updateStats(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody RunStat stats) {
        return this.service.updateStats(id, stats);
    }
    
}
```

```
package com.qa.project;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
//import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.qa.service","com.qa.project.domain", "com.qa.project.rest", "com.qa.repository"})

public class QaProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QaProjectApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.qa</groupId>
    <artifactId>QaProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>QaProject</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: The error message is already telling you what's wrong and how to fix it. You haven't shown us your Spring configuration, but presumably it doesn't include a bean of type `com.qa.project.service.RunStatService`

Comment: "I am currently following a tutorial" => Does that tutorial really suggest having a class, both annotated with `@Entity` and `@SpringBootApplication`? This is really not a good idea and lets me believe that this is not a good tutorial.

Comment: make 'RunStatService' final:
private final RunStatService service; 
please test this solution and give me a response.

Comment: @JonSkeet Which one is my spring configuration? Please don't mock me, I'm just trying to learn. Could you tell me why I need to create a bean in this instance? I assume it is something to do with how Spring operates? As you can tell, total noob here haha.

Comment: @MohammadJavad Hi, I tried this but no unfortunately. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose No it does not have that however I had it suggested to me as part of a fix for the problem I have now. I didn't quite understand how that would help in any way whatsoever but I figured the internet knew better than me so I whacked it in then forgot to take it out when it ultimately did nothing lol. But yes, the tutorial is whack; it tells you 'do this' now 'do that' but doesn't tell you why to do it so it is a struggle when i run into problems as I can't prepare a solution for a problem I don't understand. That is why I have resorted to the internet

Comment: The [Spring Boot documentation](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) is quite good, and it provides a ton of tutorials. Why not simply use these?

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is the wrongly placed `@SpringBootApplication`. A Spring Boot application has a *main* start class which bootstraps the whole application. This class should get the mentioned annotation. It is a special annotation that also already includes [component scanning](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.16/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html?is-external=true).

By default, components are scanned only in the same package, where that annotation is found, and in its sub-packages. You have placed the annotation onto your class `RunStat` in the package `com.qa.project.domain`. Thus, all components in other packages - such as `com.qa.project.service` - are not found.

The solution:

Create a class with the name `RunStatApplication` (or similar) and place it into the package `com.qa.project`. That class gets the annotation `@SpringBootApplication`. With that setup, all other components are now in sub-packages and thus are found.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. This totally makes sense and I have applied it. It seems to have maybe solved the problem? I am getting a plethora of new errors that I need to somehow address haha. The first one however was 'error creating bean with name 'RunStatController' thrown from 'Unsatisfied Dependency Exception'. I am going to try and have a think about this but if you could give me some direction I would be so grateful. Again, thank you for your input